# Blender to unity problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have few problems with importing character from blender to unity. First of all these are images of character inside unity (Idle State) and then in blender(how it should look).

Unity:
[image]

Blender:
[image]

So i guess one of the problems is double sided mesh. I checked `Double sided` but it is not working so how can i fix it.

Second problem is i guess something about weights. It looks like unity is not getting weights how it should have so does anyone have idea what is problem there.

I was trying to avoid 3d modeling but since i have done everything to my game considering engine, now i had to start learning blender and do not laugh because this is my second character (first one is just blank white mesh) :P.

Comment: It looks like it is missing bump/normal map.

Comment: What is that and how to get it?

Comment: Never mind. I got the images from blender and unity wrong. Some part is missing because it looks like the cloth is only one sided. You need to add tiny depth/width to the cloth mesh.

Comment: In Maya, you go to face mode, select all the faces and extrude them out a little-bit. I am not a blender guy and cannot tell how this is done with blender.

Comment: Ok i get it and know how i will do that one but what about cloth bending (i guess weights)

Comment: What's wrong with cloth blending?

Comment: You do not see difference between first and second picture? Look at first one, you can see belt going through cloths. Those two pictures are same position (idle) but first is from unity and second from blender so they need to be same

Comment: Typically with 3D modeling, you want to avoid surfaces that are only 1 face thick. Then things like back face culling will get called and you'll be able to see through them. My advice to avoid this in the future is to not include single faces (like the collar and coat) and to keep those as thin prisms (that way there are outward faces on all sides)

Comment: Looks like this question would be better suited for  https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the one sided was to duplicate object and scale it a little down. Problem is i get some edges but i will figure it out later.

For the second one where bone weights were problem, i simply imported .blend file into unity and it worked (since then i was importing .fbx)

BETER SOLUTION FOR SECOND ONE: Add Solidify and it's thickness property will do the job.

Comment: *"The solution for the one sided was to duplicate object and scale it a little down"* No. Using duplication to fix that is wrong. Just give it thickness. You are adding more unnecessary overhead to Unity.

Comment: Wow it is working like that. Didn't know that will work. Thanks again :)

Comment: An alternative solution would be to tweak a little bit the material you use to enable [the double sided mode](https://www.google.fr/search?q=unity+double+sided&oq=unity+double+sided).